# My Sign In Page copying the Navigation Bar for my Dashboard

Tags: reactjs

I created a Sign In Page and Dashboard Page. I created a SidebarData.js which is it will show all the data in the navigation to my Dashboard.js, but the issue is the navigation also shown in my Sign In Page.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import SignIn from './components/auth/SignIn';
import Dashboard from './components/auth/Dashboard';
import UserData from './pages/UserData';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import '../src/App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<SignIn />}></Route>
    </Routes>
    <Dashboard />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/home' element={<Home />}></Route>
        <Route path='/userdata' element={<UserData />}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If I remove the Dashboard in my App.js the navigation from my Sign In Page will  be gone, but if I Sign In the navigation for dashboard will gone also. I used React.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to enter your Home and UserData components into the Dashboard route component.
Try changing your code to be like this:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/' element={<SignIn />} />
  <Route element={<Dashboard />} >
    <Route path='/home' element={<Home />} />
    <Route path='/userdata' element={<UserData />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

And then import your SidebarData.js in your Dashboard.js like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import SidebarData from './components/auth/SidebarData '; {/*depending on where your folder is*/}

function Dashboard() {
return (
   <>
      <SidebarData />
      <Outlet />  {/*your home page and userdata page will appear along with your SidebarData */}
   </>
 );
}
export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. But there's another issue, inside the Dashboard there's no home and userdata show. What I mean is the navigation is shown but the data in navigation when I click the Home or Userdata there's nothing to show. I already try something but it doesn't work.

Comment: may i know how is your code on Home component or UserData component?
I hope after knowing I can make it easier for you

Answer (score 0):

```
try this one and no show the navbar in home page

    import React from 'react';
    import SignIn from './components/auth/SignIn';
    import { About } from './views/About';
    import { NavBar } from './components/NavBar';
    import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
    
    export const Routes = () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <NavBar />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/SignIn" component={SignIn} />
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Redirect to="/Home" />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/About" component={About} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).